# (error "Buffer *scratch* was not set up for parsing")

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'm struggling to enable CEDET on Emacs (so I can get intellisense through auto-complete and such) and I came across this weird error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Buffer *scratch* was not set up for parsing")
  signal(error ("Buffer *scratch* was not set up for parsing"))
  error("Buffer %s was not set up for parsing" "*scratch*")
  semantic-idle-summary-mode()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-660706> nil "/home/jorge/.emacs.d/conf-modes/cedet.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 991
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jorge/.emacs.d/conf-modes/cedet.el" "/home/jorge/.emacs.d/conf-modes/cedet.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/jorge/.emacs.d/conf-modes/cedet.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/conf-modes/cedet.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-280517> nil "/home/jorge/.emacs.d/varl.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 615
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jorge/.emacs.d/varl.el" "/home/jorge/.emacs.d/varl.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/jorge/.emacs.d/varl.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/varl.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/jorge/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 373
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jorge/.emacs" "/home/jorge/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262 [...]
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Here is my CEDET configuration, written after painful experimentation and reading many posts on the Internet:

```
;;
;; configuración de CEDET

;;incia CEDET
(semantic-mode 1)
(global-ede-mode 1)
(ede-enable-generic-projects)

(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-decoration-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-completions-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-cedet-m3-minor-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-highlight-func-mode)

(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t)
;(semantic-load-enable-minimum-features) ;;Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function semantic-load-enable-minimum-features)
(semantic-idle-summary-mode)
(semantic-idle-completions-mode)

(when (cedet-ectag-version-check t) ;; Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cedet-ectag-version-check)
  (semantic-load-enable-primary-ectags-support))
```

This is what I'm `require`ing at startup:

```
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'ecb)
```

and finally, my emacs version: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.2) of 2013-08-06 on -mnt-storage-buildroots-staging-x86_64-eric`

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The problem goes away if I comment the lines containing `(semantic-idle-summary-mode)` and `(semantic-idle-completions-mode)`, but I don't know if this is the proper solution or something...

Comment: Not a CEDET user, but I guess you need to run them selectively (e.g. via a mode hook; `c-mode-hook` if you want them in C buffers, etc) rather than globally.

Comment: That will rise another sort of problems that I solved searching here on Stackoverflow! (but I bet that it woulnd't happen with both `(semantic-idle-summary-mode)` and `(semantic-idle-completions-mode)`. If you mean that...)